# PHP Explode and Implode a String

Tags: php, explode, implode

I am half way done and struck at imploding on the output.

I have a string as

```
$text = "test | (3), new | (1), hello | (5)";
$text = explode(",", $text);
foreach ($text as $t){
    $tt = explode(" | ", $t);
    print_r($tt[0]);
}
```

When I print the above array, it gives me `test new hello` as needed, now, I need to put a comma like this `test, new, hello`

I searched and could not achieve hence posting here to get help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$text = "test | (3), new | (1), hello | (5)";
echo preg_replace('# \| \(.*?\)#', '', $text);
```

**EDIT:**
to reach result like 
'test',' 'new', 'hello'

```
$text = "test | (3), new | (1), hello | (5)";
$text = preg_replace('# \| \(.*?\)#', '', $text);
echo "'" . preg_replace('#,#', "', '", $text) . "'";
```

Comment: Cool, thanks, your final edit worked. Can you please explain within the preg_replace, how have you done? I will accept this answer.

Comment: @sammry, this is matching (and then substituting with empty string) using RegEx, also known as Regular Expressions. Here's quickly googled-up something that should help you get the idea and learn how to use them: http://regexone.com/cheatsheet .

Comment: by the way, if I have to quote it like this, `'test',' 'new', 'hello'`?

Comment: It matches " | (X)" pattern, just escaping | symbol, because unescaped means OR, exaping ( and  ) because it is also symbols, .*? this means everything inside will be matched "non greedy". # this is start stop signs

Comment: Don't you think regex is a bit overkill? Some simple php methods could do this eg implode?

Comment: regex is only one method with internal loop, using foreach, implode explode is overkill.

Comment: @sitilge: even if harder and somewhat hard to like at the beginning (ugly strings, aaa!), this is proper and reasonable use-case for them. It's "concise one-liner vs. iterating, using several intermediate variables" question.

Comment: @sammry: $text = "test | (3), new | (1), hello | (5)";
$text = preg_replace('#( \| \(.*?\),? ?)#', "', '", $text);
$text = "'" . substr($text, 0, -3);
echo $text;
// 'test',' 'new', 'hello'

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can push them to array and [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) later on

```
$text = "test | (3), new | (1), hello | (5)";

$text = explode(",", $text);

$arr = array();

foreach ($text as $t){
    $tt = explode(" | ", $t);
    $arr[] = $tt[0];
}

echo implode(", ", $arr);
```

Comment: Thanks 
 
by the way, if I have to quote it like this, 'test',' 'new', 'hello'?

Comment: Go for the `$arr[] = "'".$tt[0]."'";`

Answer (score 0):

1- Implode is a function in php where you can convert a array into string
  Ex-

```
$arr = array('Hello','World!','Beautiful','Day!');

echo implode(" ",$arr);

?>
```

2- Explode is a function in php where you can convert a string into array

Ex-

```
$str = "Hello world. It's a beautiful day.";

print_r (explode(" ",$str));
```

?> `